# CSS - Block or revert theme background style

Tags: css

I have a `div` from a plugin and it's components with their own CSS styles set. Unfortunately, it does not use any type of query that speciying the components inside it, neither any `!important`. So when I put the plugin inside a page with a theme with it's own CSS styles set, the theme's styles affects the components.

I think this is general CSS problem I'm facing. But in my case, it's the background. The plugin was set the background before the theme overrides it.

Plugin settings :

```
background: transparent url(background.png);
background-position: 0 50px;
```

The `background-position` in my example is vary between components.

Theme settings :

```
background: grey;
```

The problem is when I change the background to get the plugin settings back, it also overrides the background-position. The same goes with `initial` and `revert`, neiter works.

So I'm still looking for the solution to add a CSS to revert or block the theme CSS without doing anything to the plugin or the theme. TYIA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the theme CSS **without doing anything to either the plugin or the theme**, one way I can think of is to create a separate CSS file with the selector class that you want to modify, and then write your style in that also indicate its parent selector to increase specificity. Something like this...

```css
selectorsParent .selectorYouWantToOverride {
    background: transparent url(background.png) !important;
}
```

Import the new stylesheet **after** the theme and plugin's style sheets.

Comment: revert bg image is easy. it's bg position i'm fighting

Comment: Have you tried the solution with bg-position? Did it work ?

Comment: i can't. read my question again. the value is vary. even i've no idea why revert does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

***Hi,***

if I correctly understood your problem is using the `background` property to override plugins settings which is a shorthand property for all the CSS background properties.

> The problem is when I change the background to get the plugin settings back, it also overrides the background-position.

This is a normal behaviour of the CSS property `background`.

---

### What is the problem?

As you wrote, your plugin set `background` and `background-position` and then your theme once again `background`. Second use of `background` property cause overriding all background settings include it's position too.

---

### Solution

In my opinion you should set background properties separatly for each property, e.g. `background-color`, `background-image`. In this case you change just this properties which you want to, and another like `background-position` stay the same.

---

### Knowledge

The definition of CSS `background` property is described at [this W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.php).

---

***Cheers***